# Powershell, WMI Methods

Tags: powershell, syntax, wmi

using WMI with PowerShell I found something I don't understand:

```
# Syntax 1
gwmi -Class Win32_Share | gm -MemberType Method
Output: Delete, GetAccessMask, SetShareInfo

# Syntax 2
$a = New-Object "System.Management.ManagementClass" "Win32_Share" :
$a | gm -MemberType Method
Output: Create.....
```

So: why I don't get the "Create" Method using the syntax "1"?

Answer (score 3):

Because they return two different types of objects.

```
(gwmi -Class Win32_Share).GetType()
```

returns a `System.Array` instance while

```
(New-Object "System.Management.ManagementClass" "Win32_Share").GetType()
```

returns a `System.Management.ManagementObject` instance

*Note that it doesn't make sense to call Create on an already instantiated object anyway, or in other words: why do you think you need it?*

**Edit**

Your comment actually made me rethink *(finally)* and your conondrum is that you should use `-query` instead of `-class`. I have yet to figure out what the actual difference between both methods of calling is but I *assume* it's the same class/instance distinction.

```
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM meta_class WHERE __class = 'Win32_Share'"
```

Comment: Hi Lieven, thanks for help. In this case (maybe it's somehow too academic..) the method "create" makes sense since it doesn't create an object itself, but a new share.

Comment: @Purclot - I have updated the answer to adress your comment. fwiw - using the WMI commandlets is being discouraged in favour of the CIM commandlets.